# to verify whether a given space is a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $y_a, y_b ∈ \mathbb{R}$, and let
$$S(y_a, y_b) = \{x ∈ C[a, b]\;|\; x(a) = y_a \mbox{ and }x(b) = y_b\}.$$
For what values of $y_a$, $y_b$ is $S(y_a, y_b)$ a vector space?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. What is the  zero vector of your vector space?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Pick $x,x'\in S(y_a,y_b)$ and see what happens to $x-x'$.

**Hint:** Pick $x,x'\in S(y_a,y_b),\ \lambda\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$ and see what happens to $\lambda x$.

Really, I'm almost tempted to think about which defining property of vector space *not to look at*.